# Passing parameters to parameter dialog for Query-based reports

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a query-based report in which the query has some interactive ranges enabled on them.  This is great except the value is blank, or has the last values used pre-populated.  One of these is Vendor account number.  If I wanted to have this report to pre-populate the Vend account based on whichever Vendor account record is selected (the caller), how would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was easy, although hard to find.  I wasn't aware that you could access query objects from within a controller.  The solution is to create a Controller class with only a main() method defined as normal, and the `prePromptModifyContract` method overridden.  The following code will solve the problem:

```
SomeTable   someTable;
Query       query;

super();

if (this.parmArgs() && this.parmArgs().dataset() == tableNum(SomeTable))
{
    someTable = this.parmArgs().record();
    query = this.getFirstQuery();

    SysQuery::findOrCreateRange(query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(SomeOtherTable)), fieldNum(SomeOtherTable, SomeOtherField)).value(SysQuery::value(someTable.SomeField));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this, but you could override the query's init method and call to element.args().record() as in a Form.
Something like this:

```
public void init()
{
    VendTable vendTable;

    super();

    if (element.args().dataset() == tableNum(VendTable))
    {
        vendTable = element.args().record();
        //populate your ranges with vendTable
    }
}
```

I hope it works!

Comment: The problem there is the caller of the Query is the SSRS report, and the report itself cannot have a record attached.  Instead, using a controller class, the controller becomes the caller of the query and passing it to the report.